# NodeJS response not sending index.html

Tags: node.js, express, routes

```
    app.get(`/`, (req, res, next) => {
      console.log(`in / get`);
      const indexHtml = path.resolve( __dirname + '/../public/index.html' );
      res.sendFile(indexHtml);
      next();
    });
```

I'm trying to make this index.html show up on my home route using express but it's not loading. I get the console log, and I've console logged indexHTML to ensure the path is correct, but all I get is an error of cannot get.
All my other routes that are brought it are working a-ok. Just not this guy.

Comment: Can't you just use [express.static](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static)?

Comment: Missing a quote mark at the start of this string here: `/../public/index.html'`  This should have caused a visible error.  Also, you presumably want the path to be `'../public/index.html'` without the leading slash and want to use `path.join()`, not `path.resolve()`.

Comment: And, many of your quote marks look wrong.  They look like back tick marks, not regular single quotes.

Comment: Sorry the lack of a quote mark was a miss type! The lack of leading slash still does not work. The tick marks are for es6. I'm working on using them instead, but clearly I still mix and match. Fixed, but still no go.

Comment: I don't want to use join as I need an absolute path not relative

Comment: `__dirname` is already absolute so join will give you an absolute path.  And, please edit your question to fix the typo so others don't see the same problem.

Comment: Also, you can do `console.log(indexHtml)` and see what it actually is.

Comment: One problem is that you don't call `next()` or even declare it in your route handler when you are using `res.sendFile()`.  `next()` means to call the next handler in the chain, but you've already completely processed the request so you don't want any more handlers to be called.  I don't know if that's causing your problem or not, but it is definitely not correct.  What exact error do you see?

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think your call to `next()` is part of the problem.  Remove it.

Comment: It was the next! I didn't know the combination of that and sendFile would not work. My rookie mistake. Thanks! I was particularly flummoxed cause I had indeed done    console.log(indexHtml)

Comment: OK, I put that into an answer so you can finish the question.

Comment: Arielle - Do you realize that once you have an answer to your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark next to the best answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure which, over time, can earn you more privileges here.

Comment: Just checked back to see that you had put an answer. I was unsure of whether I did that or you. And no, this is the first ever time I've posted a question. I will remember this for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the call to `next()` after `res.sendFile()`.  You want the `res.sendFile()` to handle the response entirely, but calling `next()` passes on control to other handlers, probably ending up in the 404 handler and because that doesn't have to read the disk, it gets processed before `res.sendFile()` does it's job.

When you send the response, you do not want to call `next()` because you don't want any more request handlers in the chain to run.